# What makes halal slaughter really halal?

Tags: islamic-basis, meat, dhabihah

What makes halal slaughter really halal? If you include scientific proof, more plus point for me.

Comment: http://www.themodernreligion.com/misc/an/an_slaughter.htm

Answer (score 4):

Because Halal slaughter is intended to inflict the least pain on the animal by cutting the arteries which suddenly drains the brain from blood and renders the animal brain-dead and  thus unable to feel the pain any longer. Saying "Bismillah" and facing the animal towards Qibla are also meant to highlight the awareness that the slaughter is a gift of God and therefore done with observance of His oversight and moderation, thus sanctifying what could be an otherwise unrestrained greedy exploitation of animals.

See Wikipedia entry [*Dhabihah*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhabihah) for a more comprehensive explanation and also modern questions in regards with legitimate slaughter.

Comment: You could think of adding this article to your answer [Study conducted](http://www.themodernreligion.com/misc/an/an_slaughter.htm)